# getting error connecting native app with android mobile using adb

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to run a sample application on my mobile using adb connector.

adb is working fine but while running the app I get the following errors:

So kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

> - What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components
>   [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].
>   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and co
>   lete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK M
>   ager.
>   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workst
>   ion to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
>
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debu
>     option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 9.726 secs
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
>   set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Comment: The error message is clear. You need to set up Android development environment (SDK). Able to run `adb` commands does not mean your Android development environment is ready.

Comment: install required sdk from your android studio